# How to read numbers that are stored in a text file and then store them in a list or array as integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Actually, I am making a random number guessing game and I have to get input from user of 50 numbers from user and then store them in a file then read those numbers from the file and then select any 25 numbers randomly from these numbers and then show them in a 5x5 grid and I have some more requirements too but I have done all the coding for them but the problem I am facing is that I don't know how to read these numbers from file and store them in an array or list as integers.

```
import numpy
from random import sample
f = open("Python_Project.txt","w+")
count = 0
print("Enter 20 unique numbers within the range 1-100")
while (count<20):
    x = int(input())
    if x > 0 and x < 101:
        f.write(str(x))
        f.write(" ")
        count += 1
    else:
        print("Please Enter a number between the range")
f.close()
myfile = open("Python_Project.txt", "r")
contents = myfile.read().split(',')
myfile.close()
print(contents)
```

['12 23 54 3 8 35 33 76 98 55 6 8 3 12 43 56 65 33 78 89 '] I am getting this but I need these numbers as integers so that I can sort them and do other things

Comment: Why are you writing numbers _space seperated_ and split them _by comma_ ?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285684/how-to-read-numbers-in-text-file-using-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285684/how-to-read-numbers-in-text-file-using-python) - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271503/python-read-numbers-from-text-file-and-put-into-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271503/python-read-numbers-from-text-file-and-put-into-list) - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812578/trying-to-read-a-txt-file-with-numbers-into-a-list (forget the sorting part)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812578/t)

Answer (score 0):

```
new_content = []
for i in contents[0].split(" "):
    try:
        new_content.append(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        continue
print(new_content)
```

Add this code at the last of your file.
Here new_content is the array of integers .
This code will only work as expected if you split with space instead of comma in your code

Comment: Thank you bro but i tried this code at the end it only prints the first index value not the entire list